# Go on Google App Engine returns error: API error 1 (mail: INTERNAL_ERROR): Internal error

Tags: google-app-engine, email, go

I'm a bit lost. Sending email via GAE does not appear to work. The error thrown is: 
`Couldn't send email: API error 1 (mail: INTERNAL_ERROR): Internal error`

I have tried several different Sender addresses but non seem to work *consistently*. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Locally every seems OK (no mail send of course but the log shows send hypothetical emails).
The code:

```
func (coinflip *Coinflip) mailParticipants(context appengine.Context, key *datastore.Key)     {
  participants, _, _ := coinflip.fetchParticipants(context)
  for i := range coinflip.Participants {
    msg := &mail.Message{
                  Sender:  "X...@gmail.com",
                  ReplyTo: "X...@gmail.com",
                  To:      []string{participants[i].Email},
                  Subject: "What will it be? " + coinflip.Head + " or " + coinflip.Tail + "?",
                  Body:    fmt.Sprintf(confirmMessage, "http://www.flipco.in/register/" + key.Encode() + "?email=" + participants[i].Email),
      }
    if err := mail.Send(context, msg); err != nil {
        context.Errorf("Couldn't send email: %v", err)
    }
  }
}

const confirmMessage = `
Someone created a coin toss with you.
Please confirm your email address by clicking on the link below:

%s
`
```

The complete code can be found on Github: https://github.com/haarts/flipco.in

Thanks for your help!

With kind regards,

Comment: There are restrictions on the email addresses you can send email from in App Engine. Have you tried the email address of an app administrator?

Answer (score 2):

What's your appid? There's a known problem that if your appid is the same as the gmail account name used to create the app, mail sending will fail. See here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5320